# Proving a function is a probability density function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function

I got this question as a challenge question from my lecturer and I have no idea how to even approach it. I need to show that
$$ f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left( \frac{x}{\beta} \right)^{\alpha - 1} e^{- (x / \beta)^{\alpha} }, \hspace{0.5cm} x \geq 0 $$
is a probability density function.

The lecturer gave a hint and said that I can use a change of variable to evaluate the integral.
I also know that to prove a function is a PDF that when integrated from $0$ to $\infty$, it should equal $1$. however, I don't even know where to being or what change of variable I am meant to do.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting a link to an image.

Comment: ... and don't forget to share your attempts or ideas.

Comment: What happens if you try the change of variables $y=(x/\beta)^\alpha$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original integral can be written as follows

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{\beta^{\alpha}}\cdot e^{-(\frac{x}{\beta})^\alpha}dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-(\frac{x}{\beta})^\alpha}d[(\frac{x}{\beta})^\alpha]=1$$